# Font looks different on photoshop and at website

Tags: html, css, fonts, photoshop

Simple question: Why this 2 fonts looks different at photoshop and at website.
[image]

At this picture - this first text is from html code, second is an image from photoshop. The same font, the same size - 30. But this first looks more "bold" than second. Why? I want to have a identically font as it is at photoshop (second picture).

Here css code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "SegoeWP";
src: url("fonts/play/SegoeWP.eot");
src: url("fonts/play/SegoeWP.eot?#iefix")
         format("embedded-opentype"),
     url("fonts/play/SegoeWP.woff") format("woff"),
     url("fonts/play/SegoeWP.ttf") format("truetype"),
     url("fonts/play/SegoeWP.svg#PlayRegular") format("svg");
font-weight: lighter;
}

#strona {
  width: 1120px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#Section1 
{
      font-family: "SegoeWP", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px; 
}



header, footer, article, section, hgroup, nav, figure {
    display: block;
}


 body {
  font-family: "SegoeWP", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-image:url('background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  color: #ffffff;

 }
```

And html code.

```
  <section id="Section1">  { mywebsite.NET } </section>
  <img src="mojeportfolio.png" />
```

any ideas? Greetings!

MORE

i found, that I have 3 types of SegoeWP font in folder. "SegoeWP", "SegoeWP-Light", "SegoeWP-Semibold". "SegoeWP" looks a litle bit too "bold", but this "SegoeWP-Light" is perfect and looks identical as in photoshop when i doubleclick it. How can I use it on my website? When I change this part -> url("fonts/play/SegoeWP-Light.*"), nothing change at website. What is wrong?

Comment: You're specifying several font file types, how do you know which one is being used? Perhaps they don't match.

Comment: there is only SegoeWP.ttf at the moment

Comment: @whoah Maybe you are not seeing the picture in actual size in photoshop.. They can't be different.. when the size is 30px, IT SHOULD BE 30px EVERYWHERE.. Try pressing ctrl+0 in ps.. to see in actual size..

Comment: @Miro Markarian -> it is 30px. I tested on photoshop, and this font is "Light". "Semibold" and "regular" looks similar at this on website. How can I use "Light" option on website? `font-weight: lighter;` change nothing :(

Comment: i found, that I have 3 types of SegoeWP font in folder. "SegoeWP", "SegoeWP-Light", "SegoeWP-Semibold". "SegoeWP" looks a litle bit too "bold", but this "SegoeWP-Light" is perfect and looks identical as in photoshop when i doubleclick it. How can I use it on my website? When I change this part -> `url("fonts/play/SegoeWP-Light.*")`, nothing change at website. What is wrong?

Comment: Most browsers don't support font-weight:lighter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

photoshop handles fonts a lot differently than a web browser ... because photoshop used functions like smoothing, kernel and others the font will almost always look different in a browser

Comment: uh, ok. So it is not possible to make this font less "bold"?

Comment: you can use 
    font-weight: lighter;

Comment: i add it, this change nothing - the same situation

Comment: try changing the value from lighter to 300 or 400.

Comment: try this and see if it changes anything .. your css might be overidden by another style .. <span style='font-family: "SegoeWP";font-weight: 100;'>mywebsite.net</span>

Answer (score 5):

To get the same result try using `font-smoothing: antialiased`, and reducing the font size so it matches your Photoshop image.

The biggest difference is because Adobe Photoshop will not do subpixel font-smoothing—unlike most browsers. In your example image this is easily visible if you zoom in(see the color shifts around the edges). Windows has a history of using an extra crisp form of subpixel font rendering, which exacerbates the problem as the perceived font weight can change severely.

Smashing Magazine has an excellent [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/) on font rendering.

Comment: More like `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you are adding the css to the right location sometimes that could be the issue.  For full notes on how to lessen the weight of a font you can find it here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_font-weight