# Arial italic looks bold

Tags: css, fonts

I used Arial italic on a website. I did it this way:

```
font-family: Arial;
font-style:italic;
font-weight:100;
```

In Photoshop Arial italic looks as thin as regular is. On the website it looks bold. I dont know if this is related to faux styles. If yes, how can I use the real Arial italic (In my fonts folder theres just one font, called Arial, no ArialItalic or something). If no, where does this come from and can I do something about it?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h84Vv/2/

Of course I don't know, if this is related to my system.

Comment: do you have any exemple ?! (jsFiddle) can you try to add : <i>blabla</i> for see if same result ? you can try : font-weight:normal;

Comment: Agreed with @artSx `font-weight:normal;` should work. But your code will give us a good idea of what issue are you facing.

Comment: Checked on my end. Doesn't look bold. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Worth a read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161710/photoshop-mock-up-font-isnt-same-as-in-html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534197/font-looks-different-on-photoshop-and-at-website

Comment: I tried that (See updated fiddle), looks the same. <i>-tag doesnt help either. Does it look bold for you, too?

Comment: Tested it in IE, looks bold. What OS are you using? I'm using Win7.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use another font?

Comment: No, its just Arial. I found out, that there is no Arial italic. Its faux. The Arial they used in the layout is Arial MT. I will use a fontstack (Because the customer shurely has Arial MT on their system). Brower rendering stuff isnt my problem.

Comment: Mine is Win7, IE 10 and FF lastest

Comment: Thats weird. We have the same browser, OS and I think that should mean, we have the same font.

Answer (score 0):

```
font-family: Arial;
font-style:italic;
font-weight:100;
```

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/h84Vv/2/

If you want to text bold

*Italic*

**Bold**

Comment: you want font-weight bold?

Comment: He says, it looks bold. So normally, he means, he doesn't want it to look bold. - @falguni

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the Arial font family contains a regular, italic, bold, and italic bold typeface, and with your settings, you get the italic typeface. Setting `font-weight: 100` has no effect, since Arial has no typeface lighter than normal.

If you have removed the italic typeface, then browsers may use normal typeface as slanted (“fake italic”, though it’s not really italic but slanted, in a synthetic way). It should not cause the text to look bold. In the absence of more information (like a description of the font family under the name Arial in the system and some screen shots) it is impossible to analyze the issue further.