# Photoshop fonts compare with browser fonts family looks different

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I have used "Arial Bold" and "Calibri bold" font family for site and it's looks different when i compared psd image font family vers browser html font family. why it's looks different as i used same font family on psd image and put same font family in html code.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font looks different on photoshop and at website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534197/font-looks-different-on-photoshop-and-at-website)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to bold fonts in Photoshop:

The first one is to use "Faux Bold":

[image]

Resulting in:

[image]

The second (and IMHO, correct) one is to select the font style:

[image]

Resulting in:

[image]

(Notice the difference between the two)

I suspect you have used the first method instead of the second in PSD