# Html web fonts looks different as compare to photosohp font

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I have been used "Arial regular", "Arial bold" and "Calbri bold" in my html file and it's look different as compare to photoshop font family. As it not match pixel to pixel match with these font family why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font looks different on photoshop and at website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534197/font-looks-different-on-photoshop-and-at-website)

Answer (score 1):

When using photoshop the fonts use different functions like smoothing, thin, kernel, etc  but your browser does not use any of those functionalities which is why they appear to be a little different.

Of course you can try and make it look a little similar by using css style such as :

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

or

font-weight: 400; (weight can be changes according to available values in css)